# Tkinter pickle save and load

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

help me please how can I use the pickle save if I have a lot of entry and I want to save all in one file and load form the file for each entry separately?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pickle tkinter widgets. You will have to extract the data and save just the data. Then, on restart you will have to unpickle the data and insert it back into the widgets.

Comment: I have found a solution with a dictionary  the string value and then call for an update for the entry when I pick a file to load